# How to count locals in ANS-Forth?

Tags: forth, gforth

While developing [BigZ](https://github.com/Lehs/ANS-Forth-libraries), mostly used for number theoretical experiments, I've discovered the need of orthogonality in the word-set that create, filter or transform sets. I want a few words that logically combinated cover a wide range of commands, without the need to memorize a large number of words and ways to combinate them.

```
1 100 condition isprime create-set
```

put the set of all prime numbers between 1 and 100 on a set stack, while

```
function 1+ transform-set
```

transform this set to the set of all numbers p+1, where p is a prime less than 100.

Further,

```
condition sqr filter-set
```

leaves the set of all perfect squares on the form p+1 on the stack.

This works rather nice for sets of natural numbers, but to be able to create, filter and transform sets of n-tuples I need to be able to count locals in unnamed words. I have redesigned words to shortly denote compound conditions and functions:

```
: ~ :noname ;
: :| postpone locals| ; immediate

1 100 ~ :| p | p is prime p 2 + isprime p 2 - isprime or and ;
1 100 ~ :| a b | a dup * b dup * + isprime ;
```

Executing this two examples gives the parameter stack ( 1 100 xt ) but to be able to handle this right, in the first case a set of numbers and in the second case a set of pairs should be produced, I'll have to complement the word :| to get ( 1 100 xt n ) where n is the numbet of locals used. I think one could use >IN and PARSE to do this, but it was a long time ago I did such things, so I doubt I can do it properly nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand (LOCALS) but with patience and luck I managed to do it with my original idea:

```
: bl# \ ad n -- m
  over + swap 0 -rot
  do i c@ bl = +
  loop negate ;
\ count the number of blanks in the string ad n

variable loc#

: locals# \ -- 
  >in @ >r
  [char] | parse bl# loc# !
  r> >in ! ; immediate
\ count the number of locals while loading

: -| \ -- 
  postpone locals#
  postpone locals| ; immediate
\ replace LOCALS|
```

Now

```
: test -| a b |  a b + ;
```

works as LOCALS| but leave the number of locals in the global variable loc#.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should drop `LOCALS|` and parse the local variables yourself.  For each one, call `(LOCAL)` with its name, and end with passing an empty string.

See http://lars.nocrew.org/dpans/dpans13.htm#13.6.1.0086 for details.

Comment: If you say so. I don't know how it works, but will try to find out.

Comment: The document says that (local) is undefined both in interpret and compile mode and it seems to be implementation dependent.